# Sql server sorting field values

Tags: sql, sorting, multiple-columns

Is it possible to sort fields left to right in sql server? for example

```
----    DO  MO  BC  NI  SC
Total   22  44  53  57  24
Prod A  0   24  0   24   0
Prod B  0   0   0   20   7
Prod C  0   20  0   13  13
```

Would become:

```
----    NI  BC  MO  SC  DO
Total   57  53  44  24  22
Prod A  24   24  0   0   0
Prod B  20   7   0   0   0
Prod C  20   13  13  0   0
```

this would ignore the column names which I can update after.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you could do this using Dynamic SQL to build the final query based on evaluating the values in the columns, but why would you want to do this? It'd mean that you potentially have a totally different result set every time the query runs, which would lead to mass confusion for end users and analysts.

Comment: items.OrderBy(x=>x.Total)

Answer (score 1):

While I would never recommend using this method (as this seems to be geared towards presentation logic), it did intrigue me to find a way to accomplish the results.

Here's one method using both `pivot` and `unpivot`.  You lose your column headers (but they aren't accurate any longer after the transformation anyhow):

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT field, field2, field3
  FROM 
     (SELECT field, do, mo, bc, ni, sc
      FROM yourresults) p
  UNPIVOT
     (field3 FOR field2 IN 
        (do, mo, bc, ni, sc)
     )AS unpvt
  ),
CTE2 AS (
  SELECT field, 
    field3,
    row_number() over (partition by field order by field3 desc) rn
  from cte
  )
SELECT field, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
FROM (
  SELECT field, field3, rn
  FROM CTE2) P
PIVOT 
(
  max(field3)
  FOR rn IN
( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5] )
) AS pvt
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aaed1/12)

Comment: I knew this works in excel but not in sql.Thanks Guys this is perfect, works like a charm.